# Issue with forEach

Tags: angularjs, foreach

To get a specific key I am using `forEach` in AngularJS, but inside `forEach` control is not going.

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

```
var stories = {"1": "What is the name of your primary school?", 
               "2": "What is your favorite color?", 
               "3": "What is your favorite pet?"};

function addStories(stories) {
  var changed = false;
  angular.forEach(stories, function(story, key) {
          //my logic.....
  });
}
```

Comment: can you post your stories array how it looks like

Comment: its not array its a map Object :( :O o_0

Comment: please post your object also

Comment: var theMap =  {
       "1": "What is the name of your primary school?",
       "2": "What is your favorite color?",
       "3": "What is your favorite pet?"}     I have the value(What is your favorite color?) using that value i need to get the key(1) using forEach in angularJS.

Comment: forEach does not work on arrays. You can iterate over the keys and then get the values though `angular.forEach(Object.keys(stories) ...`

Comment: *Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection, which can be either an object or **an array**.* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: `//my logic.....`  Yeah, that's the rub of the thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  var theMap = { 
    "1": "What is the name of your primary school?", 
    "2": "What is your favorite color?", 
    "3": "What is your favorite pet?"
  };

  $scope.data = {
    keys: [],
    values: []
  };

  angular.forEach(theMap, function(value, key) {
    $scope.data.keys.push(key);
    $scope.data.values.push(value);
  });


}]);
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="key in data.keys">key: {{key}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="value in data.values">value: {{value}}</div>

</body>
```

result:

```
key: 1
key: 2
key: 3
value: What is the name of your primary school?
value: What is your favorite color?
value: What is your favorite pet?
```

**Additional example:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.getQuestionNumber = function(questions, target_question) {
    angular.forEach(questions, function(question, number) {
      if(question === target_question) {
        $scope.data.question_number = number;
      }
    })
  };

  var questions = { 
    "1": "What is the name of your primary school?", 
    "2": "What is your favorite color?", 
    "3": "What is your favorite pet?"
  };

  var target_question = "What is your favorite color?";

  $scope.data = {}; //put results in here
  $scope.getQuestionNumber(questions, target_question);

}]);
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>Question number: {{data.question_number}}</div>
```

There are a couple of things to note about `angular.forEach()`:

1) *You* are not the one that is calling the function here:

```
                               |
                               V
angular.forEach(questions, function(question, number) {
  return "1";
}
```

Rather, some angular code is calling that function.  That means you have no way of getting the return value from the function.  Somewhere in the angular source code there is something like this:

```
//Definition of forEach() function:
function forEach(obj, func) {
  ...
  ...

  func(val, key);
}
```

Note that angular does not store the return value of func() anywhere.  So, no matter what your function returns,the return value is discarded.

2) Furthermore, angular calls the function inside a loop:

```
  function forEach(obj, func) {
    ...
    ...
    var obj_properties = obj.getOwnPropertyNames();
    var i;
    var len = obj_properties.length;

    for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
       ...
       ...
       func(val, key);
    }
  }
```

So if you write:

```
    angular.forEach(questions, function(question, number) {
      if(question === target_question) {
        $scope.data.question_number = number
        return;  //***WHAT DOES THIS DO?***
      }
    })
```

...that return statement is equivalent to `return undefined', which results in the following:

```
    //Inside the Angular loop:

    for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
       undefined;   //func(val, key) gets replaced by it's return value each time through the loop
    }
  }
```

...and that does not succeed in breaking out of the angular for loop--so ALL the properties will be checked--even after a match is found.

I don't know if you can reorganize your data or not, but if you reorganize your data like this:

```
  var questions = { 
    "What is the name of your primary school?": "1",
    "What is your favorite color?": "2",
    "What is your favorite pet?": "3"
  };
```

Then you can just write:

```
  var target_question = "....";
  var number = questions[target_question];
```

...which is much more efficient than having to step through the array, element by element, until you find the match.

Comment: At last i came up with this idea. 
var theMap = $scope.securityQuestionsList;
       var ans = securityQuestion;

       for (var v in theMap) {
       
          var t = theMap[v];
             if(t==ans)
              {
                 return v;
              }
       }
Its working Superb thanks for all your helps @7stud

Comment: @SujeethDamodharan, I'll add an example that does what you want using angular.forEach(), which you can compare to your solution.